# PCA in R: Error in svd(x, nu=0, nv=k) : Infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, pca

My dataframe contains about 26k rows with 129 variables. I've made sure all of the variables are numeric and do not have any NA values (used na.omit). Using the function prcomp() on my dataframe tells me "Infinite or missing values in x". What might I be overlooking then?

Answer (score 1):

Did you also make sure none of them are infinite? As that's the other part of that message?

Easily check all this with:

```
all( is.finite( your.data.frame ) )
```

Comment: The output for all(is.finite(my.data.frame)) is FALSE. The output for all(is.infinite(my.data.frame)) is also FALSE. What does that suggest?

Comment: I used the "sapply" function instead of "all" to check for infinite/NA values and discovered one column with infinite values. Removed that and ran the PCA function and it worked! Thank you for your input, Sirius.

Comment: Glad to help, people helping themselves is the best.